# upload_max_filesize= 64MB, но contact form 7 даже 9 мб не загружает

Tags: файлы, изображения, сервер, upload

php.info показывает, что размер загружаемого файла может быть до 64 мб.
я использую Contact Form 7 + drag&drop upload плагин, чтобы загружать файлы через сайт. Вот больше 2 МБ не грузит, хотя в "медиафайлы" все большие файлы загружаются.
И еще файлы *.zip не принимает, где можно снять эти ограничения?

Спасибо заранее

Comment: Сервер-то какой используется?

Comment: сервер  провайдера Windows

Comment: А веб-сервер на этом Windows какой стоит и каковы его настройки?